# Can someone please list and/or explain all the Windows Store app permissions?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store, windows-rt, windows-store-app

Is there a list somewhere already? If not, can you list all the permissions available to Windows 8 apps, and what permissions they have by default? This is good info to know you are secure with your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Permissions are Divided into two categories: **General Use Capabiltiy** and **Special Use Capability**.

### General Use Capability

2. **Removable storage:**
   Provides programmatic access to files on removable storage, such as USB keys and external hard drives, filtered to the file type associations of the app.
3. **Microphone:**
   Access to the microphone’s audio feed, which allows the app to record audio from connected microphones.
4. **Webcam:**
   Access to the webcam’s video feed, which allows the app to capture snapshots and movies from a connected webcam. Only grants access to the video stream excluding Audio stream.
5. **Location:**
   Access to location functionality, which you get from dedicated hardware like a GPS sensor in the PC or is derived from available network info.
6. **Proximity:**
   Enables multiple devices in close proximity to communicate with one another. This capability is typically used in casual multi-player games and in apps that exchange information. Devices attempt to use the communication technology that provides the best possible connection, including Bluetooth, WiFi, and the internet. This capability is used only to initiate communication between the devices.
7. **Internet and public networks:**
   Outbound access to the Internet and public networks through the firewall. Almost all web apps use this capability.
8. **Home and work networks:**
   Inbound and outbound access to home and work networks through the firewall. This capability is typically used for games that communicate across the local area network (LAN), and for apps that share data across a variety of local devices.
9. **Music library:**
   Access to your music library and playlists, including the capability to add, change, or delete files. This capability also includes music libraries and playlists in the music library on HomeGroup computers, plus music file types on locally connected media servers.
10. **Pictures library:**
    Access to your pictures library, including the capability to add, change, or delete files. This capability also includes pictures libraries on HomeGroup computers, along with picture file types on locally connected media servers.
11. **Videos Library:**
    Access to your videos library, including the capability to add, change, or delete files. This capability also includes videos libraries on HomeGroup computers, along with video file types on locally connected media servers.

### Special Use Capabiltiy

Special use capabilities are intended for very specific scenarios.

1. **Enterprise authentication:**
   Typically used in line-of-business apps that connect to servers within an enterprise. Windows domain credentials enable a user to log into remote resources using their credentials, and act as if a user provided their user name and password.
2. **Shared User Certificates:**
   Access software and hardware certificates, such as certificates stored on a smart card.
3. **Documents library:**
   Access to the user's Documents library, filtered to the file type associations declared in the package manifest.

[Detailed Explanation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations :

### General-use capabilities :

1. Music
2. Pictures
3. Videos
4. Reovable Storage
5. Internet and public networks
6. Homes anf work networks
7. Appointments
8. Contacts
9. Code generation
10. AllJoyn
11. Phone calls
12. Recourded Calls Folder
13. User Account Information
14. VOIP calling
15. 3D Objects
16. Read Blocked Messages
17. IoT Low-level Bus Hardware
18. IoT System Administration

### Device capabilities :

1. Location
2. Microphone
3. Proximity
4. Webcam
5. USB
6. Humain interface device
7. Point of Service
8. Bluetooth
9. Wi-Fi Networking
10. Radio state
11. Optical disc
12. Motion activity

### Special and restricted capabilities

I will not enumerate this list here (its quite long), have a look on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations).

Comment: What new infomration is contained in tihs answer that wasn't contained in Ankit Mishra's answer over 3 years ago?  This question was with regards to Windows 8, UWP that support Windows 10, don't have anything to do with this question.

Comment: First, because a google search falls people here even if there are looking for W10.
Second, take time to look closer both answers and sources, and you will be able to find several responses to your first question.